# How to know if user clicked on X in the form

Tags: c#, winforms

Thanks to everyone who takes effort on answering my question.

I'm using WinForms C#, and on the MainForm_Load, I'm calling the Login form for the user. The Login form contains the X button (the default button on the top-right) and Loginbutton.

Now...

If the user decides to click on the X button the Login form closes and so should the MainForm, which I know how to do. But... if the user clicks on LoginButton the LoginForm should close, but the MainForm should stay opened.

Any idea hwo to do that ?

Comment: _How_ do you show the login form?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using `ShowDialog` to show the login form, then you can do this:

```
if(LoginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   //login ok
}
```

your login form should set the DialogResult to OK before it closes, but only for successful login, like so:

```
if(LoginSuccess){
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;//this will also close the form
}
```

Comment: You don't need the Close() call; setting DialogResult automatically hides the form and returns execution to the ShowDialog() line.

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Huh... never knew that. I don't like it though, not a behaviour I would expect from setting a property

Answer (score 3):

You can check `e.CloseReason` in the `Form.FormClosing` event!

```
Private Sub YourForm_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
        'Closed by user
        '
        'Do something like
        'Application.Exit()
        '
        'or close both forms
    Else
        'Other close reason
    End If
End Sub
```

The [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx) will be UserClosing if the X is clicked or the user presses Alt + F4.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative option :

You can disable the X button in login form by setting the  **ControlBox** property of login form to **False**

Answer (score 0):

On your Login button's click event handler, add a call to this.Close()

This should close the Login form, without affecting the Main form.